# Can I update eglibc to a non-vulnerable version using Debian Squeeze 6 on x86_64 architecture?

Tags: debian, security

I'm currently attempting to update eglibc on Debian Squeeze 6 on x86_64 architecture from version 2.11.3-4, which is vulnerable to the GHOST exploit, to version 2.11.3-4+deb6u4, which isn't vulnerable to the GHOST exploit.

My issue is that it looks like I need to update to Debian Squeeze 6 LTS in order to do so, but Debian Squeeze 6 LTS only supports i386 and amd64 architectures. **Short of upgrading my distribution to Debian Wheezy 7, is there any other way I can update eglibc to a non-vulnerable version?**

Many thanks - much appreciated.

Comment: Rebuilding the sources on the relevant architecture is always an option, and provided system resources are sufficient should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Debian, `amd64` is `x86_64` so Squeeze LTS is a viable option for you. See my answer to [your question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244341/ghost-vulnerability-fix-for-debian-6-squeeze) for details.

Comment: Thanks so much Stephen. Slightly embarrassed to admit that I didn't realize amd64 == x86_64.